# Internet Shortcut in python

Tags: python

I have a problem. Let's say I have a website (e.g. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)). Is there any way to create a file with a .url extension linking to this website in python? (I am currently looking for a flat, and I am trying to save shortcuts on my hard drive only to apartment offers posted online matching my expectations ) I've tried to use the os and requests module to create such files, but with no success. I would really appreciate the help. (I am using python 3.9.6 on Windows 10)

Comment: what do you mean by `create a file with .url extension linking to this website`?

Comment: after double clicking on it, appropriate website would open in browser. (Same effect you receive when you highlight website URL and then drag and drop it on your desktop for example)

Comment: Why not just save the links in a text file, then input that into your python script? Although, I'm not really understanding what this accomplishes that Excel or Google Sheets couldn't do.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward. I had no idea what .URL files were before seeing this post, so I decided to drag its URL to my desktop. It created a file with the following contents which I viewed in Notepad:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68304057/internet-shortcut-in-python
```

So, you just need to write out the same thing via Python, except replace the URL with the one you want:

```
test_url = r'https://www.google.com/'

with open('Google.url','w') as f:
    f.write(f"""[InternetShortcut]
URL={test_url}
""")
```

With regards to your current attempts:

> I've tried to use os and requests module to create such file

It's not clear what you're using `requests` or `os` for, since you didn't provide a [Minimal Reproduceable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you'd tried so far; so, if there's a more complex element to this that you didn't specify, such as automatically generating the file while you're in your browser, or something like that, then you need to update your question to include all of your requirements.